# cannot open a webpage through imagebutton - android studio

Tags: java, android, android-intent, imagebutton

the following is my java file for one of the fragments that am using to have multiple image buttons which open multiple weebpages.
please help.
treat me as a noob.

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu8_layout, container, false);
    return rootview;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Button bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_click_login);
    btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
        Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://google.com"));
        startActivity(myWebLink);
    });
    }
}
```

here is the related xml file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000">


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bt1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:onClick="goToSo"
    android:text="some" />
```

Comment: guys i found the solution. leaving it here for anyone who might find it helpful. in the fragment the **findViewById** doesnt work, to make it work we have to use getView().findViewById()